# Spring Boot 2 Hikari data sources misconfigured?

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

Trying to configure 2 Hikari data sources, but only one is picked up properly and the Hikari logging shows the config. Other than setting one as Primary, the properties are the same.

ActivityConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class ActivityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "activity.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties activityDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "activity-datasource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "activity.datasource.hikari")
    public HikariDataSource activityDataSource() {
         System.out.println("properties url = " + activityDataSourceProperties().getUrl());
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = activityDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class)
                   .build();
        return hikariDataSource;
    }
```

SubscriptionConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class SubscriptionConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "subscription.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties subscriptionDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "subscription-datasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "subscription.datasource.hikari")
    public HikariDataSource subscriptionDataSource() {
        System.out.println("properties url = " + subscriptionDataSourceProperties().getUrl());
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = subscriptionDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class)
                   .build();
        return hikariDataSource;

    }
```

application.properties:

```
#HikariCP  config
activity.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://.../activity
activity.datasource.username=XXXX
activity.datasource.password=YYYY
activity.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
activity.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
activity.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
activity.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=300000
activity.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000
activity.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=10
activity.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
activity.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=15000
activity.datasource.cachePrepStmts=true
activity.datasource.prepStmtCacheSize=250
activity.datasource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
activity.datasource.useServerPrepStmts=true
activity.datasource.useLocalSessionState=true
activity.datasource.rewriteBatchedStatements=true
activity.datasource.cacheResultSetMetadata=true
activity.datasource.cacheServerConfiguration=true
activity.datasource.elideSetAutoCommits=true
activity.datasource.maintainTimeStats=false
activity.datasource.hikari.pool-name=ActivityPool

#HikariCP  config
subscription.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://.../subscription
subscription.datasource.username=XXXX
subscription.datasource.password=YYYY
subscription.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
subscription.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
subscription.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
subscription.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=300000
subscription.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000
subscription.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=10
subscription.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
subscription.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=15000
subscription.datasource.cachePrepStmts=true
subscription.datasource.prepStmtCacheSize=250
subscription.datasource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
subscription.datasource.useServerPrepStmts=true
subscription.datasource.useLocalSessionState=true
subscription.datasource.rewriteBatchedStatements=true
subscription.datasource.cacheResultSetMetadata=true
subscription.datasource.cacheServerConfiguration=true
subscription.datasource.elideSetAutoCommits=true
subscription.datasource.maintainTimeStats=false
subscription.datasource.hikari.pool-name=SubscriptionPool
```

Everything starts up fine, but only the "activity" data source settings are logged by Hikari. And on shutdown, there is no mention of "*SubscriptionPool*".

Only logging that comes out from Hikari:

```
09:51:38.422 [main] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - ActivityPool - idleTimeout has been set but has no effect because the pool is operating as a fixed size pool.
09:51:38.422 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - ActivityPool - configuration:
09:51:38.423 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - allowPoolSuspension.............false
09:51:38.424 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - autoCommit......................true
09:51:38.424 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - catalog.........................none
09:51:38.424 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionInitSql...............none
09:51:38.424 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTestQuery.............none
09:51:38.424 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTimeout...............60000
09:51:38.424 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSource......................none
09:51:38.424 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceClassName.............none
09:51:38.424 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceJNDI..................none
09:51:38.425 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
09:51:38.425 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - driverClassName................."com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
09:51:38.425 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - healthCheckProperties...........{}
09:51:38.425 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - healthCheckRegistry.............none
09:51:38.425 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - idleTimeout.....................300000
09:51:38.425 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - initializationFailTimeout.......1
09:51:38.425 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - isolateInternalQueries..........false
09:51:38.425 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:mysql://.../activity
09:51:38.431 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - leakDetectionThreshold..........0
09:51:38.431 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - maxLifetime.....................1800000
09:51:38.431 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - maximumPoolSize.................10
09:51:38.431 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - metricRegistry..................none
09:51:38.431 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - metricsTrackerFactory...........none
09:51:38.431 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - minimumIdle.....................10
09:51:38.431 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - password........................<masked>
09:51:38.431 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - poolName........................"ActivityPool"
09:51:38.432 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - readOnly........................false
09:51:38.432 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - registerMbeans..................false
09:51:38.432 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - scheduledExecutor...............none
09:51:38.432 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - schema..........................none
09:51:38.432 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - threadFactory...................internal
09:51:38.432 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - transactionIsolation............default
09:51:38.432 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - username........................"XXXX"
09:51:38.432 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - validationTimeout...............15000
```

Maybe related is that an Entity object I have specifying the *subscription* schema, is being reported as part of the *activity* schema, saying the table doesn't exist there (true!) when calling a *find* method.

Did I misconfigure something, or is there a Hikari/Boot issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered that I needed to add *@EnableJpaRepositories* on each configuration class. Doing that and both datasources were configured as expected. Also had to add *@Qualifier* to each **DataSource** argument used in the *entityManagerFactoryBean* method in each config class:

```
@Bean(name = "subscriptionEntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                       @Qualifier("subscription-datasource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                   .packages("com.acornmedia.activeusers.subscription.repo")
                   .persistenceUnit("subscription")
                   .build();
```